# android studio uses persian/arabic numbers for set margin in attributes window

Tags: android-studio

I am using android-studio on windows 10, when I set the margin to my view in the attributes window, android-studio uses **Persian / Arabic** numerals and this causes an **error** and **the margin does not work**.[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I was trying to create a joke like "What do you want, Roman numerals" (like III, XIV) but it was weak at best. In the English-speaking world we refer to our numerals as Arabic:  1,2,3,....

Comment: Btw, that would be a bug and should be reported if not already fixed -- they obviously need to format those numbers in a locale-independant fashion before writing them to the document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to change region format to English

[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tevFC.jpg)